# how to list aws latest/sorted files when having more than 1000 files

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

how to get aws objects / files by date or bigger than date even when having more than 999 objects in the same prefix without pagination?

- i need to be able to pull files from the last X days or last 10 files, even if there are too many objects in the path.
- The solution of listing in pagination is not what im looking for since i can have A LOT of files in the same destination.
- thoughts about having a lambda function that keeps last 10 files on object upload even was considered, but searching if there is any other good way
- using node-js. aws-sdk.
- the method listObjectsv2 does not include any sorting/filtering except the key prefix which is not so helpful

  ```
    return this.connection
  .listObjectsV2({
    Bucket: destinationBucket,
    Prefix: path,
    Delimiter: '/',
  })
  .promise();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to calling `ListObjects` are:

- Use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects
- Trigger an **AWS Lambda function** on object creation/deletion, and code the function to maintain a database of objects (eg in DynamoDB)

  - If you only care about the past *n* objects, you could simply update a list kept in Parameter Store or an S3 object (as a simple data store)